# Can I run C++ projects in Ubuntu from an NTFS partition?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, ntfs

I have an extra NTFS partition to store data that I want to use both from WIndows and Ubuntu.
I made a C++ project there. 
It was a simple Hello World console application.

I get this error when I run it.

```
sh :1 :/media/Data1/blah/blah/project/bin/debug/project :permission denied
```

My fstab file looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
```

Blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL="DellUtility" UUID="5450-4444" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="4248184648183ADD" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="OS" UUID="20081BCC081B9FB8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="bc712346-c70f-4bc6-9f21-48bae91b8b02" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="1915e08f-1961-437f-900a-3dd37a26118b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="bcb714f1-7428-4e5f-8cf9-73ae724ada57" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda8: LABEL="Data1" UUID="7FCF22B82B6665CB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda9: LABEL="Data2" UUID="411A8CDC1D33E6FA" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: see [Changing the default gnome mount options (gnome-mount)](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/internal/computing/docs/public/gnome_default_mount_options.html) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/16730/default-mount-options-on-auto-mounted-ntfs-partitions-how-to-add-noexec-and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remount with exec while running

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/Data1
```

#### Making it stick across reboots:

I suggest adding

```
LABEL=Data1 /media/Data1  auto auto,exec 0  0
LABEL=Data2 /media/Data2  auto auto,exec 0  0
```

to your fstab file.

Reboot, done.

Comment: Since I dual boot with Linux and Windows and use Windows many times, am I not being at a risk if I allow  the 2 NTFS partitions  to execute their binaries? The NTFS  partition may contain viruses from Windows. I am not very proficient at security. Do you suggest I use an ext4 partition instead? (since Windows can't use ext4)

The sole reason for using NTFS was to I could view it both on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: It doesn't matter: windows has all (local) partitions in 'exec' by default. The flag only affects the linux side. If you run wine (windows emulation), you might want to checkout clamav (free virus scanner) or similar.

Comment: I have a good anti virus on Windows since windows has all (local) partitions in exec. Yes I'm referring to the linux side itself. Will linux be vulnerable to harmful programs that come in while using Windows is what I'm asking.

Comment: @learner Linux will be far **less vulnerable** (viruses/malware depend on highly specific OS characteristics). Note: If you run wine, you ***can*** run Windows programs on linux. Now: again, linux **isn't more vulnerable** since, obvious, windows can run the same programs. Add to that that windows malware is usually triggered from browser, registry or (side-channel) installed registered components, all these factors will be absent on the linux side, so even if your windows side is infected, these malicious programs will not actually be loaded when booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: Long story short: Ubuntu malware and Windows malware are largely mutually exclusive. Mounting 'exec' is equally secure as Windows's defaults. (In practice it doesn't matter since the malware isn't geared for Linux/Wine)

Answer (score 3):

You can, if you remove noexec option from fstab

Comment: remove or change it to "exec" ?

Comment: remove, i think. You need to remount partition after this, or reboot the whole system

Comment: Does my fstab file look all right? I don't want to mess up things.

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,exec /path/to/mountpoint` to remount with `exec` while running. This is likely a USB disk

Comment: It isn't. It is an extra partition in my only hard disk.