# Cannot run C compiled program on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, permissions, execute

I have written a simplest C script `hello.c` and then 
compiled it using gcc.
The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

This code is straight from
[How to Compile and Run a C Program on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/CAN_e14/Readings/How%20to%20Compile%20and%20Run%20a%20C%20Program%20on%20Ubuntu%20Linux.pdf)

I have compiled it using the command `gcc -o hello hello.c`
Then I got the program `hello` on the same directory.
I tried to execute it by

```
./hello
```

however it didn't work.
I've also tried

```
ls -l
```

and the result is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname myname    1234 Nov 21 00:00 hello
```

I tried to give a executable permission to this file by

chmod 777 hello

but the permission didn't change.
I also tried

sudo chmod 777 hello

But it still didn't work.
The file and the script is in the different drive (physically on the same drive yet different partition to that of the Ubuntu is installed).

What can I do to execute the `hello` in Ubuntu?
What is wrong with my procedure?

Comment: What was the message when you tried to run chmod?

Comment: @Sunny as it is written ` -rw-r--r-- 1 myname myname    1234 Nov 21 00:00 hello`

Comment: see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097443/can-i-run-c-projects-in-ubuntu-from-an-ntfs-partition

Comment: what is the output of sudo chmod 777 hello

Comment: Do you have necessary priveledge to run sudo? i.e are you a root user or a user that can use sudo?

Comment: @Sunny `chmod 777 hello` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have permissions to the drive, you can set permissions using chown
 `sudo chown -R yourusername /media/username/mountpoint`
 Replace mountpoint with the actual mount point name.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, `chown -R myname /media/mountpoint` returned nothing. (I know that mountpoint is the name of the mount point of the drive).

Comment: After chown please compile the program again

Comment: Recompiled and run it but It returns `bash: ./hello: permission denied`.
`chmod 777 hello` returns nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Your procedure seems fine (works at my Ubuntu system). It seems you do not have the rights to change permissions at the drive where your executable is located. Does the procedure work at your personal home folder?